# display json data console log

Tags: javascript, json

i am facing an issue in javascript, i want to display response `status` success or error in `console log` but my code it is not working.

what should i do? anyone help me?

my code

```
...
                client.request.post(url, options)
                .then(function (data) {
                    console.log(data);   
                    console.log(data.response.status);   //undefined
                if (data.status == 200) {
                    console.log("success",data);                    
                }
                }).catch(err => {
                console.log("Error", err)
}
```

console log

```
{status: 200, headers: {…}, response: "{"status":"success","data":"User settings updated."}", attempts: 1}

{status: 200, headers: {…}, response: "{"status":"error","data":"Number of Agents cannot be exceed."}", attempts: 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on

```
{status: 200, headers: {…}, response: "{"status":"success","data":"User settings updated."}", attempts: 1}
```

you're getting a response that contains JSON as a string within its response field, and you'll need to parse it to get a real object:

```
...then(function (data) {
    data.response = JSON.parse(data.response);
    console.log(data);   
    console.log(data.response.status);
});
```

Comment: thanks i try [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/51685/akx)

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your response data.
it should be like this:

`{status: 200, headers: {…}, response: {"status":"success","data":"User settings updated."}, attempts: 1}`

Please verify the value of the key 'response'.

If value of 'response' is not a json object then parse it using `JSON.parse(data.response)`

Comment: thanks i try [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6250402/hong4rc)

Answer (score 0):

Your response is:

```
{
  "status": 200,
  "headers": {},
  "response": "{\"status\":\"success\",\"data\":\"User settings updated.\"}",
  "attempts": 1
}
```

So `data.response` is a string, not an object.

You can use:

```
console.log(JSON.parse(data.response).status);
```

instead of:

```
console.log(data.response.status);
```

Comment: thanks i try [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6250402/hong4rc)